# Java Stream API: Optional if not null proceed

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

I would like to have opportunity to make null check inside the stream:

```
firstItem = array.stream().min(myComparator).get();
if(firstItem!=null){
     name = firstItem.getData().get("Name")
}
```

Is it possible to get `name` right from the Stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `Optional` can't contain null values, so your code will either execute the conditional, or fail with an exception at `get()`.

You could change the `get()` to `orElse(null)`; but you'd still need the separate conditional.

Instead, use `Optional.map`, then `orElse`:

```
String name = 
    array.stream()
        .min(myComparator)
        .map(m -> m.getData().get("name"))
        .orElse(someDefaultValue);
```

Of course, if you don't want to assign a default value, you can omit the final `orElse`, and make the variable type `Optional<String>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String name = array.stream().min(myComparator) //
.map(item -> item.getData().get("Name")) //
.orElse("No Name");
```

Comment: You'd need to use `orElse(null)` instead of `get()`; but why unwrap and then immediately re-wrap the optional?

Comment: My bad, went with OP code and tried to wrap it in `Optional`, corrected now

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetly there is no way to avoid either some kind of check or a default value (as was already posted in previous answers). Having said that, there is a nice way of doing checks with optionals. Let me give you an example.
I've created simple class for tests.

```
 class ExampleData
    {
        private String name;
        private int value;

        public ExampleData(String name, int value) {
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ExampleData{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", value=" + value +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

Now lets write a simple test method.

```
 public void testApp()
    {
        ArrayList<ExampleData> array = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                new ExampleData("TestName", 1),new ExampleData("TestName1", 2)));
        Optional<ExampleData> min = array
                .stream()
                .min(Comparator.comparingInt(ExampleData::getValue));

               min.ifPresent(System.out::println);



    }
```

Notice that i didn't use `get()` right away. Instead i used `ifPresent` method when i wanted to extract value. I don't know if you ever used C# language but this approach remind me of `?` operator from c#.

In c# you would simply do something like this

```
String name = possibllyNullValue?.getName();
```

so here in Java you can do something similar with `ifPresent()`

Of course `ifPresent` returns void so it can be inconvenient in some cases.